# "long vectors not supported yet" error in Rmd but not in R Script

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am operating matrices with R 3.1 and RStudio 0.99.

I have my R Script and with cmd+enter it works without problem.

I created an Rmd for reporting but I have this error

```
Error in lazyLoadDBinsertVariable(vars[i], from, datafile, ascii, compress,  : 
  long vectors not supported yet: ../../../../R-3.3.1/src/main/connections.c:5600
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> lazyLoadDBinsertVariable
Execution halted
```

Is there a way to bypass that error?

This seems to be a dupicate of [Large Matrices in R: long vectors not supported yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335692/large-matrices-in-r-long-vectors-not-supported-yet)

but the difference is that this only happens when trying to create an Rmd, not in any other case

Comment: how many no of observations are you working with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large Matrices in R: long vectors not supported yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335692/large-matrices-in-r-long-vectors-not-supported-yet)

Comment: it is a 28630x50247 matrix but the error only appears with the Rmd

Comment: Also check this: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/572

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I also ran into this today, and fixed it by using `cache.lazy = FALSE` in the setup chunk in my .Rmd.

So what is inside of the first chunk in my R Markdown file looks like this:

```
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE, warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE, cache.lazy = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I just wanted to add that for whatever reason, I had to access it from `options` instead of `opts_chunk$set`. So I had `options(cache = TRUE, warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE, cache.lazy = FALSE)`. I'm on RStudio 3.2.2 if that makes any difference

Comment: This is probably sue if you are caching a very big R object.  That was my problem.

Comment: Using the original answer with `knitr::opts_chunk$set` worked for me on R 3.5.1.

Comment: For more background read https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache-lazy.html

Answer (score 9):

I am getting the same error in my .rmd file while trying to knit it to pdf.
The incriminated code chunk was cached.

> Is there a way to bypass that error?

Removing the 'cache = TRUE' or setting it to FALSE seems to fix the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14017730)

Comment: Hi. I wasn't caching. I cached now and it happens with or without caching. A possible solution was already commented.

Comment: Thank @etienne for the clarification. I don't get why I am being downvoted because the solution I suggest actually fixed the problem for my script.