# R long vectors not supported yet on R 3.3.2

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate hilbertcurve (of Bioconductor package) of level 16 in R. It takes about 4^16=4 Billion points. I want to generate the hilbert curve of genome (size about 3 billion).

But I am getting this error

```
long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:1668
```

I am using 64 bit version (R 3.3.2) so my guess is I can use vectors of length > 2^31. Also, my RAM is about 350GB.

The command I am using is

```
itr=4^16
hc = HilbertCurve(1, itr, 16, mode = "pixel", title = "pixel mode",start_from = "topleft")
```

Even when I am reading the whole genome sometimes R is crashing in the process.

I have read the other similar questions on this topic but could not find the solution. Please help me what should I use for this problem.

Comment: this might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335692/large-matrices-in-r-long-vectors-not-supported-yet