# Error in complete.cases(x, y): long vectors not supported yet: complete_cases.c:192

Tags: r, r-mice

I apologize that I cannot upload a reproducible dataset, but my data is on a secure server.

I am running multiple imputation with chained equations using the `mice` package in R. I have a dataset with around 130,000 rows and around 11 columns. I have missing data on 4 columns (one variable has around 50% missingness).

The imputation procedure stops at the first iteration, throwing the following error message:

> Error in complete.cases(x, y): long vectors not supported yet: complete_cases.c:192

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you try to put aside the variable with more than 50% of NAs ?

Comment: I just tried that with the same result..

Comment: If there is a problem with the complete case it could be that all individuals have at least one missing value. Is this the case?

Comment: No, 42% have no missing values. I can run the mice(data, maxit=0) without problems. I then specify the predictormatrix and run: mice(data, m=5, maxit=10) and here the error is thrown.

Comment: I simulated your dataset (130,000 rows, 11 columns, all variables with ~ 50% missingness) and I don't get an error when running `mice`. Can you give any other information about the dataset, particularly the classes of the variables, the way you set up the prediction matrix, etc?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who might be still looking for a solid solution, there is none.

R objects are [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24336251/6326375) by the size of 32bit `int` meaning you can't have more than `2**31 - 1 == 2147483647` elements per matrix/dataframe.

Whereas in this particular case `130000*11` is far below the limit, *multiple* imputations usually result in a humongous final matrix. Try fewer iterations/imputations and see how it goes.

The only ones to blame here are core R developers since they persistently avoid 64bit integers.

The original code that produces the errors is here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/complete_cases.c

Other packages affected by this:

- https://github.com/jkrijthe/Rtsne/issues/55
- https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/279